# is it possible to access the sharepoint list newform.aspx using modal popup in 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i am working in sharepoint 2007. i want to open the newlistform.aspx using modal popup. before that i worked the samething in sharepoint 2010. sp2010 having sp.ui.dialog.js file, but moss2007 dont have this file, is it possible to access, if yes please help me to resolve this.
Thanks and Regards,
Rasu.U

Answer (score 0):

No, the dialog framework was first introduced in SharePoint 2010. If you want something similar you will have to code it yourselft using fancyBox or something like it.

Comment: i want to show the list NewForm.aspx in radwindow, could you provide the sample code for this please

Comment: No, this is not a site where people just give you code. Come up with a specific question and we'll try to answer it.